# manipulate select options with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value and text of multiple select boxes and add them to a hidden fields, can any one please help.

```
<form>  
 <select  class="select" name="select" id="select">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1.99">1</option>
            <option value="1.99">2</option>
            <option value="1.99">3</option>
            <option value="1.99">4</option>
            <option value="1.99">5</option>
            <option value="1.99">6</option>
            <option value="1.99">7</option>
            <option value="1.99">8</option>
          </select>

   <select class="select" name="select2" id="select2">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="2.99">1</option>
          <option value="2.99">2</option>
          <option value="2.99">3</option>
          <option value="2.99">4</option>
          <option value="2.99">5</option>
          <option value="2.99">6</option>
          <option value="2.99">7</option>
          <option value="2.99">8</option>
        </select>

    </form>

   $(function() {

//function to go through all of the select boxes and get their values based on their change state.

var qty=0;var price=0;items="";
$(".select").each(function() {

    $(this).change(function(){
        qty =($(this).text());
        price = (($(this).val()) * qty);
        items = ($(this).prevAll(".descriptionsColor").text() );
    });

});



//function to add items to shopping cart when add button is clicked.
$('#my-add-button').click(function() {

    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000)+200);
    $('input[name=my-item-id]').val(randomNumber);
    $('input[name=my-item-name]').val(items);
    $('input[name=my-item-price]').val(price);


});
```

I need to get the value and text of the select boxes on change and multiply them to get a price, also get the description of the item which is in a span tag with a class.

Do I need to use array variables to store the values and text and prices?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

selecting the selected value can be achieved like this:

```
$("#Select1").val();
```

selecting the text from the selected item can be done this way:

```
$("#Select1 option:selected").text()
```

so you would say

```
qty = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
price = $(this).val();
```

then you have the correct qty and price
you can multiply them and print it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

To Read Select Option Value

```
$('#selectId').val();
```

To Read Selected Text

```
$('#selectId>option:selected').text();
```

Comment: I have a lot of select boxes in one page, can I not iterate through them with the given class and get the required value and text on their change state. thanks